Minimum remaining values heuristic more powerful than degree heuristic
When selecting a new variable to assign a value to in CSP assignment backtracking search, common heuristics include:

MRV heuristic: pick the unassigned variable with the fewest remaining values in its domain.
Degree heuristic: pick the unassigned variable involved in the most constraints.

Many resources I've found online, including the ubiquitous AIMA book, claim MRV tends to be more powerful than the degree heuristic - without proof or further discussion.
Could anyone provide proof or further justification of this statement? Obviously, toy examples can be constructed where each dominates the other, so I'm curious as to how we reach a claim that one is "generally more powerful" than the other.
